# AppleGlot 4.0 produces nothing in _NewLoc

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization

Apparantly Apple finally updated AppleGlot. It's called 4.0 (although the download page names it 3.4).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but nothing is produced in the _NewLoc folder when running 'appleglot populate'. My .app bundle is placed in the _NewBase folder in my environment.

The output produces some warnings or info messages:

```
Duplicate bundles found - first="/checkout/MyApp/AppleGlot/ja/_NewBase/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework", second="/checkout/MyApp/AppleGlot/ja/_NewBase/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A"
Duplicate bundles found - first="/checkout/MyApp/AppleGlot/ja/_NewBase/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework", second="/checkout/MyApp/AppleGlot/ja/_NewBase/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/Current"
Whoa
```

These three messages are repeated 10 times or so. Notice that the duplicate bundles refer to a symbolic link file within the framework, not an actual duplicate bundle. I think that's fairly normal for frameworks. The "Whoa" seems like a debug log that shouldn't have made it to release. ;-)

This duplicate warning shouldn't be fatal I think, but nothing is produced in the _NewLoc directory and the operation is ended with "Done". Nothing that indicates that it doesn't work.

I'm getting a feeling that it's AppleGlot 4.0 that's been released prematurely - or there's just some basic concept that I'm not getting. I'm not an AppleGlot pro. Unfortunately the old Appleglot version doesn't seem to be available for download anymore, so I can't crosscheck with earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there was a bug in AppleGlot.  Fortunately, a new version which fixes this issue has been posted:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=localization